# Avoiding Temporary Variable in Subscript Operator

Tags: visual-c++, reference, subscript-operator

I have a class v which dynamically allocates an array of doubles. Entries is a pointer to the beginning of this array. Spacing allows me to skip over entries, for example, if I wanted to only consider every third entry, spacing would be 3.

```
double& v::operator[] (const int n) {
    return entries[n*spacing]; 
}
```

This subscript operator compiles but causes heap corruption. Based on my web searches, I think Visual Studio is storing the result of "entries[n*spacing]" in a temporary, and then returning a reference to the temporary. Heap corruption occurs when I try to write to this reference to deallocated memory.

Does anyone have ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

> I think Visual Studio is storing the result of "entries[n*spacing]" in a temporary, and then returning a reference to the temporary.

That is incorrect. Assuming `entries` is defined as `double entries[];` or `double* entries`, then `entries[i]` returns a reference and is that reference that gets returned by your subscript operator.

The source of your problem is somewhere else. Perhaps in `n*spacing` being outside the array bounds, or the whole `entries` being deallocated by the time the reference is accessed.

Comment: Further inspection showed that entries was invalid. Thanks K-ballo.